# How to re commit same changes in git branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I am using git for a weeks now. I am working in a feature branch, sometimes when I push code into my branch it shows lot of conflicts with develop branch. so I this time I followed following steps to avoid unwanted conflicts and problems at work place :(

1. git branch abc
2. git checkout abc
3. did my work
4. git stash
5. git pull origin develop
6. got conflicts
7. Resolved conflicts and also git stash pop
8. git commit-m'message' // Don't know how merging removed lines which are not part of conflict
9. git push origin

Now these step resulted in committing of 2 files, one in which I resolved conflicts and one in which I worked. Say File1 and File2 respectively.

Now I need to re push my code but only file2 i.e one in which I worked not in which I did conflict resolving and all.

But git status will show nothing as I have already done all the committing and pushing.
Also during some of the auto-merging the necessary code is removed from File1. How to bring that back?

Any help would be appreciated?

As I am still learning GIT so any explanation would help me and others.

I am using BITBUCKET.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For #1 & #2: They can be combined -- `git checkout -b abc`

For #4: Why did you stash? I believe you should have committed your changes here.

For #6: Conflicts where? On your newly created feature branch? That shouldn't be possible.

A typical work-flow would be as follows:

1. Make sure the main branch (master, or developer, or whatever) is up-to-date. I'll use *master* for this example.

   - `git checkout master`
   - `git fetch`
   - `git rebase origin/master`
2. Create and checkout the feature branch

   - `git checkout -b featureBranch`
3. Make changes
4. Commit changes to *featureBranch* (ideally, this will be done multiple times; not a single large commit)

   - `git add .`   # This is just one example; add selectively, as-is appropriate
   - `git commit`
5. Push local *featureBranch* to the remote, for review or whatever

   - `git push origin featureBranch`
6. When ready (e.g. reviewed and approved), merge *featureBranch* to *master*

   1. Rebase *featureBranch* against the latest *master*

      - `git checkout featureBranch`
      - `git fetch`
      - `git rebase origin/master`
   2. Make sure the *master* is up-to-date

      - `git checkout master`
      - `git rebase origin/master`
   3. Merge

      - `git merge --no-fast-forward featureBranch`

This workflow, via rebasing *featureBranch* before merging & using non-fast-forward merging, will result in a linear, yet delineated, history of *master*.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton for rhis clear and step wise explanation Jamie! Much appreciated. Can you tell me difference between rebase and pull?
#4 I stashed because someone told me to do so, earlier I use to commit only.
#6 Got conflicts in a file in which I did not even work.
did not understand this behavior.

Comment: So is there a way to re commit the changes which we have already pushed on server in our branch?
As my merge request is not approved I need a resolution for this.

Answer (score 1):

To extend previous answer, I would add: Git stash will save your changes in a "pocket" if they are not ready for a commit. But your changes are ready, so it is not necessary.

About your question in previous comment (I do not have enough reputation for answer you in a comment): git pull update your local repository and your working directory with the changes in the remote repository, is a shortcut for git fetch followed by git merge. But, as git merge have some drawbacks about the history, could be useful to used git fetch + git rebase instead.

Git rebase works locally, so it could be used in an homologous way to git merge, but not git pull!. Many answers will explain better than me about git rebase, I hope to help a little bit.

Comment: Your answer did help! Thanks Marilia15 for taking time out to answer. 
Do you know a way to reset git push in particular branch?

Comment: I have been checking the link of "git push --help" and I think you mean "git push nameRemoteRepo currentLocalBranchOrCommit:remoteBranch" for instance git push origin HEAD:master

Comment: marilia Thanks for getting back. What does this command will do?
 I used this git push -f origin last_known_good_commit:branch_name by following git log.
It didn't help much though.